# Android Emulation Manager and SDK Manager not starting in xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android

[image: this how its shows]

I can't run SDK manager and Android Emulator Manager, after I have  updated SDK, please help me to find out and fix it.

Comment: "Please check the output window for additional information." My guess is you should check the output window, it might have additional information.

Comment: thanks for yor infirmation, i have noticed that output window, but no infirmation provided related to this error., its been empty , but application runs in my device when i connect it with usb

Comment: Where did you install Android SDK? If it is not in the location Xamarin bits are expecting, there would be some problem.

Comment: The Xamarin update that was pushed out broke that.  Try opening and running your project in Xamarin Studio.  See if Xamarin studio finds it.  I had this issue as well.  Once I went back to Visual Studio it worked.